# App crashing while taking native memory snapshot with DDMS

Tags: android, memory-leaks, ddms

I am trying to find the memory leaks in native code of my android 4.1 application using DDMS.
In some scenarios when I take the "snapshot current native heap usage" my app is crashing with the following

**logs** :

```
06-04 19:10:12.741: D/DdmHandleNativeHeap(3130): **** read 68788 bytes from '/proc/3130/maps'
06-04 19:10:12.741: A/libc(3130): @@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree addr=0x6785e768
06-04 19:10:12.741: A/libc(3130): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 3136 (JDWP)
```

Same scenarios are working fine without taking the snapshot.
I am unable to figure out whether there is a problem in my app or it is in the ddms. Also I am not able to get the memory dump to analyse memory leaks.

Please help with the reasons/workaround so that I can take the memory dump.

Comment: Please help me
I'm blocked ....